# Why does setlocale give me ? instead of normal letters?

Tags: c, locale, codepages, setlocale, codepage-437

Programming language: C

IDE: CodeBlocks

Compiler: GNU GCC Compiler

OS: Windows 7

My cmd defaults to code page 852, so I decided to use setlocale(), to set it to code page 437 using

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "English_United States.437")
```

But doing so would make some letters/symbols display as '?' instead. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you need to save your file as UTF8 or switch to a Unicode TrueType font like "Lucida Console". Are you using "Raster Fonts" in your terminal?

Comment: @KeineLust    Both "Lucida Console" and "Consolas" still give me '?' and the letters/symbols are printed using a for loop to increment a char variable, which is printed out for every increment.

Comment: for(int x=0; x<256; x++){
    printf("%d: [%c]\n", x, x);
}

Comment: `setlocale()` adjusts how *the program* interprets input and encodes output.  It does nothing about how other programs or the OS do those same things.  If two programs (e.g. yours and the terminal window in which you launched it) want to exchange text then they need to agree on the relevant aspects of the locale.  You can't change it on just one side and expect satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found 2 solutions.

1.
You can change the systems default code page under control panel, but it will require to restart the computer and is very impractical, but you can use raster fonts.

2.
Using "system("chcp 437");" will set the code page to 437, but you will need to use a font like "Lucida Console" to display characters/symbols as raster fonts for some reason can't print characters/symbols correctly if you change the code page like that.